# markercluster not showing individual markers when clicked

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

The following code is showing the clusters, but when i click on any cluster, it does not show individual markers, rather it simply shows the same cluster. The markers themselves are gotten from an external service and it is working fine.

I'm also getting markers shown on the map, which are not part of any clusters.

The markers are fontawesome markers btw and i'm not getting any errors in th chrome dev console.

Here is my code:

```
        dt = MyService.getviewportpoints(nelat, nelon, swlat, swlon);
        dt.then(
              function (data){
                //console.log(data);

                    if(markerArry.length >0){
                        for (var i = 0; i < markerArry.length; i++) {
                            markerArry[i].setMap(null);
                        }
                        markerArry = [];
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < data.data.pnglist.length; i++) {
                    var star = data.data.pnglist[i];

                    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(star.lat, star.lon);
                    var roto = 0;
                    if (star.marker_path == "fontawesome.markers.PLAY"){
                        roto = 270;
                    }
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatLng,
                          map: mapInstance,
                          icon:{
                                path: eval(star.marker_path),
                                scale: 0.2,
                                fillColor: star.marker_fillcolor,
                                fillOpacity: 0.7,
                                rotation: roto
                                }
                    });
                    markerArry.push(marker);
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                        alert('info');
                    });
                }
                markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(mapInstance, markerArry);
                });
```

Comment: This might help you https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/examples.html

Comment: Thanks @Verma, I tried them all and they worked but the code i pasted above does not.

Comment: @Verma Shared link is not working, please remove it from here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem and I solved it by specifying the maxZoom property of MarkerClusterer like this:

```
var mcOptions = {maxZoom: 15};
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(mapInstance, markerArry, mcOptions);
```

Try different zoom values to see what works best for you!
Hope it helped!